# Queue with C++ for learning

Tags: c++, queue

Just started learning `c++` and I need to create a queue and need some help.
Can anyone point me where I`m wrong or if I did anything right, and I really want to learn how to do this. So, any help will be very appreciated.

```
typedefstruct int Fila;
Fila * cria_fila(void); 
void inserir_item(Fila * f, int v); 
int remover_item(Fila * f);
int fila_vazia(Fila * f); 


Fila * criar_fila (void) { 
Fila * f = (Fila *) malloc(sizeof(Fila)); 
f->n = 0; 
f->ini = 0; 
return f; 
}

int fila_vazia(Fila * f) { 
return (f->ini == NULL); 
}


void inserir_item (Fila * f, int v) { 
ElemFila * n = (ElemFila*)malloc(sizeof(ElemFila)); 
assert(!(n == NULL)); 
n->info = v; 
n->prox = NULL; 
if (!fila_vazia(f)) 
f->fim->prox = n; 
else
f->ini = n; 
f->fim = n; 
}

if (n==NULL) {printf("sem memoria\n"); exit(1);}

int remover_item (Fila * f) { 
ElemFila * t; int v; 
assert(!fila_vazia(f)); 
t = f->ini;
```

- `cria_fila()`: create queue
- `fila_vazia()`: empty queue
- `inserir_item()`: insert item on queue
- `remover_item()`: remove item on queue

Comment: EN: Nice that you trying to learn c++. Two things: a) malloc is for c, in c++ is not recommended use this. b) Try to check on youtube for videos related in this, also in portuguese, we have very good material.  PT: Legal que você está aprendendo c++. Duas coisas: a) malloc é para o c, em c++ não é recomendado usá-lo. b) Tente verificar no youtube sobre vídeos relacionados a este assunto, mesmo em português, temos ótimos materiais.

Comment: You have used real bad naming conventions for your functions.